# Gridview column headers autowrap, how to prevent?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, header, word-wrap

**Background:**

I have a gridview which is very wide. Some of the headers have a space in them. Because of this the second word of each header is wrapped to the second line. How do I prevent this?

**Previous Attempts:**

So far, I've tried the following with no luck.

1. Tried setting the `<ItemStyle Wrap="False" />` property in the `<boundfield...>` tag
2. Tried setting the `HeaderStyle-Wrap="false"` attribute in the gridview tag
3. According to http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t292904-gridview-header-wrap.html I needed to remove it from all parent objects. I removed it from all and it still wraps.
4. I tried setting the width of each column in the databound tag. This did not work.
5. I've tried setting `Wrap="false"` in the `<headerstyle` tag

**SceenShot**

[image]

**Question:**

How do I prevent the header text in a gridview from autowrapping in a very wide gridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was just creating an arbitrarily large width for the gridview as to let it have enough room. The only downfall to this is that it doesn't dynamically grow and shrink depending on how much space it actually needs. Not a real solution so if somebody has a better solution post it.

Answer (score 6):

I put this on every column:

```
 headerStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Wrap="false"
```

Answer (score 3):

add this style definition on page:

```
.myGrid th
{
     white-space: nowrap !important;
}
```

Where `myGrid` - CssClass property value of your GrridView

Comment: That didn't have any effect. Thanks for trying though

Comment: Could you post final html with the header row?

Answer (score 0):

in gridview's properties, set **Styles-> Header Style-> Wrap** to False

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me.

Codebehind (C#):

```
GridView.CssClass = "NoWrapRows";
```

CSS:

```
.NoWrapRows tr
{
     white-space: nowrap !important;
}
```

Inspired by [Yuriy Rozhovetskiy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/360171/yuriy-rozhovetskiy).